# Illegal characters problem after XSLT conversion

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is output date our XML file:

**XML**

```
<attributes>
<![CDATA[Wodoodporność: 3 ATM - Średnica: 62 mm - Rodzaj: Męskie - Materiał: Stal nierdzewna - Materiał paska: Skóra - Mechanizm: Kwarcowy - Funkcje: Wielofunkcyjność - Szkiełko: Mineralne - Rodzaj produktu: Zegarek na rękę - Opakowanie: Oficjalne pudełko]]></attributes>
```

Transform in:
**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(attributes)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:element name="{translate(substring-before($token, ': '), ' ', '_')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($token, ': ')" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently I get **Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <Wodoodporność>3 ATM</Wodoodporność>
  <Średnica>62 mm</Średnica>
  <Rodzaj>Męskie</Rodzaj>
  <Materiał>Stal nierdzewna</Materiał>
  <Materiał_paska>Skóra</Materiał_paska>
  <Mechanizm>Kwarcowy</Mechanizm>
  <Funkcje>Wielofunkcyjność</Funkcje>
  <Szkiełko>Mineralne</Szkiełko>
  <Rodzaj_produktu>Zegarek na rękę</Rodzaj_produktu>
  <Opakowanie>Oficjalne pudełko</Opakowanie>
</output>
```

Some text are incorrect. Does anyone have any solution.

Example add: `<Średnica>[CDATA[ 62 mm ]</Średnica>`

Or any other solution to solve this issue?

Comment: "*Some text are incorrect.*" What exactly is "incorrect"?

Comment: @michael.hor257k this tags are not colored: https://prnt.sc/16l5yjh I think now when I paste this and try convert to XML I cannot import products from this converted xml due to this issues right ?

Comment: But the failure of StackOverflow's code snippet highlighter is not indicator for XML well-formedness violations.

Comment: The result here is already a well-formed XML document. There is no need to convert it. If your target application does not accept it, then we need to know why. Just wrapping the text in CDATA will not help if the application does not recognize `Wodoodporność` as a valid XML element name (as apparently is the case with SO's coloring algorithm).

Comment: It is just a very poor and wrong implementation of the rules for element names in https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/src/languages/xml.js#L13 which seems to cover only ASCII letters while XML allows a wide range of Unicode letters.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3256 on highlight.js, perhaps they can fix their XML language mode to cater for XML's Unicode support in XML names.